# How to display submenu from PopupMenu without Dismissing Android

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have Java show popup menu function and xml below It work, but I want to display both Min menu and sub menu when user click on main Item.
For example When user Click on Price display child of price, and don't hide the main like price or type of product..., and if click type of product display child of type of product but don't hide main.

Here the result I expect to be.

[image]

Show popup menu java

```
//Filter Menu
    public void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        android.widget.PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dailydeal_filter, popup.getMenu());
        //popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }
```

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/category"
        android:title="Price">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="Price From 10-100"></item>
            <item android:title="Price From 100-200"></item>
            <item android:title="Price From 200-300"></item>
            <item android:title="Price Higher then 300"></item>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/type_product"
        android:title="Type Product">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="Buy Sale"></item>
            <item android:title="Business Directory"></item>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: anybody please answer this question is it possible or not?